# Crear una columna sin sin registro en la base de datos al para una Grid en syncfusion "columna falsa"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor

Estoy generando una Grid a partir de una vista que consulta varias tablas. Necesito agregar una columna que será editada por el usuario el usuario ingresando una cantidad para que la fila pueda guardarse como un nuevo registro en un par de tablas. Es por esto que la columna realmente no está generada en la base de datos, ya que no hay realmente un registro que contenga esa cantidad.

````
                                                    .Datasource(ds => ds.URL("GetOrderData_VISTA_ITEMS_PRESUPUESTO_ACTIVO").Adaptor(AdaptorType.UrlAdaptor))
                                                    //.AllowScrolling()
                                                    //.ScrollSettings(col => { col.Width(520).Height(300).EnableVirtualization(true); })
                                                    .AllowPaging()
                                                    .AllowFiltering()
                                                    .QueryString("COD_SUBCAPITULO")
                                                    .Locale("es-CO")
                                                    .AllowResizeToFit(true)
                                                    .AllowResizing(false)
                                                    .AllowMultiSorting()
                                                    .AllowSorting()
                                                    .PageSettings(page => page.PageSize(7))
                                                    .ClientSideEvents(eve => eve.ToolbarClick("clickedderecha"))
                                                    .FilterSettings(filter => { filter.FilterType(FilterType.Excel); })
                                                    .EditSettings(edit => { edit.AllowAdding().AllowDeleting().AllowEditing().EditMode(EditMode.Normal); })
                                                    .ClientSideEvents(e => e.Load("load_VISTA_ITEMS_PRESUPUESTO_ACTIVOGrid").Create("create_grid_ITEMS_PRESUPUESTOGrid").ActionBegin("inicio").ActionBegin("inicio_grid_VISTA_ITEMS_PRESUPUESTO_SIN_CONTRATOGrid").Create("create_grid_VISTA_ITEMS_PRESUPUESTO_SIN_CONTRATOGrid"))
                                                    .ToolbarSettings(toolbar =>
                                                    {
                                                        toolbar.ShowToolbar().ToolbarItems(items =>
                                                        {
                                                            items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.Search);
                                                        });
                                                    }).Columns(col =>
                                                    {
                                                        
                                                        col.Field("COD_ITEM").HeaderText("CÓDIGO").IsPrimaryKey(true).Visible(true).Add();
                                                        col.Field("NOMBRE").HeaderText("NOMBRE").Add();
                                                        col.Field("CANTIDAD").HeaderText("C. PRESU.").Add();
                                                        col.HeaderText("C. A REG").EditType(EditingType.NumericEdit).Add();
                                                    })
                                                )```
La columna en referencia es la última. En estos momentos, primero no me está tomado el valor por defecto y tampoco me está guardando el valor que ingreso cuando edito la columna, si alguien me puede ayudar le quedo muy agradecido
````

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución en la la documentación oficial :

```
}).Columns(col => {    
col.Type("checkbox").HeaderText("").Field("").Width("60").AllowFiltering(false).AllowSorting(false).Add();
col.Field("COD_ITEM").HeaderText("CÓDIGO").IsPrimaryKey(true).Visible(false).col.Field("NOMBRE").HeaderText("NOMBRE").Add();
col.Field("CANTIDAD").HeaderText("C. DISPONIBLE").Add();
col.HeaderText("C. ADD").Template("<input value=0 />").Add();
```

agregué dos campos editables, el de check y un input, comparto los links para que amplien la informacion:
https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/grid/columns?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=razor
https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/grid/editing?_ga=2.162224380.1153013492.1605824141-52632355.1601061767#default-column-values-on-add-new